# I tried this code i already passed dependency in useEffect but the api call again and again after 3/4 second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Below code i try to make get response from api and put in Movie Component. but the problem is that api hit again and again i don't why this happened.[here screen shot of api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBpt2.jpg)

```
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
  const [movielist, setmovielist] = useState([]);

  const [err, seterr] = useState("");

  const fetchMoviesHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    setloading(true);
    try {
      const reponse = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films");
      if (reponse.status != 200) {
        seterr("something is wrong");
      }
      const data = await reponse.json();
      const result = data.results;
      setmovielist(result);
   
    } catch (errr) {
    
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMoviesHandler();
  }, [fetchMoviesHandler]);

  return (
    <div>
      {movielist.map((movie) => {
        return <Movie key={movie.episode_id} title={movie.title} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Indeed... using a hook that requires a dependency array without the dependency array means that it will "run" for every render, thereby explaining what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is returning a new instance of the function on every render:

```
const fetchMoviesHandler = useCallback(async () => {
  // your function
});
```

Which will trigger the `useEffect` on every render, since this function is in its dependency array.

To tell `useCallback` to memoize the function and keep the same instance across multiple renders, it also needs a dependency array.  For example:

```
const fetchMoviesHandler = useCallback(async () => {
  // your function
}, [setloading, setmovielist, seterr]);
```

Or, at the very least, an *empty* dependency array:

```
const fetchMoviesHandler = useCallback(async () => {
  // your function
}, []);
```

Which would essentially create one instance of the function and always use it for the life of the component.

Comment: It's not necessary to add the `setXXX` dependencies gathered from `useState`. These references won't change between renders and so don't need to be included in the deps array. IIRC, `eslint react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rules don't consider these as necessary. As such, I believe that an empty deps array should do the trick here.